# Server side processing for dojo ajax

Tags: json, perl, dojo, cgi

I would like to post client side JSON data to the server where it
will be read by a cgi-bin perl script.  Been searching for examples
on how to read the data on the server side but found nothing. I am
using dojo version 1.8.1....

I can see that the request comes in on the server side to the cgi script but searching input values turns up no JSON data.

On the server side, I can see the 'cmd' parm passed from url property and I also see '1' with no data.  I have download and installed JSON.pm on the server side but can't find the JSON data from the client after the POST.

How does a server side perl script read the JSON data posted by the client??

Thx!!!

```
var xhrArgs = {
   url: "/cgi-bin/DataExport.cgi?cmd=file",
   content: xfer_data,
       headers: { \"Content-Type\": \"application/json; charset=utf-8\"},
   load: function(data) {
       alert('Posted!' + data);
   },
   error: function(error) {
       alert('Error! ' + error);
   }
 };
 dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

UPDATE..

Modified the code for dojo version 1.8.1:

```
require(["dojo/request"], function(request){
  var promise = request.post("/cgi-bin/DataExport.cgi", {
    data: xfer_data,
    timeout: 4000
     });
  promise.response.then(function(response){
    var message = response.data;
    alert(message);
 });
});
```

I still see nothing in $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'} on the server side.  The
request goes through but I still cannot find any JSON data???

```
var xfer_data = [ {"ID":"1",
"Device #":"176",
"Access #":"002-20",
"Address":"MH48 STEWART & CRANDON",
"TP":"MF",
"Curr":" ",
"Last":" ",
"Tdy":"8.6",
"-1":"8.6",
"-2":"8.6",
"-3":"8.6",
"-4":"8.6",
"-5":"8.6",
"-6":"8.6",
"Wk-1":"8.6",
"Wk-2":"8.6",
"Wk-3":"8.6",
"Wk-4":"8.6",
"Alarm":" R ",
"In":"14"} ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also finding the dojoKit [xhrPost](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/xhrPost.html) documentation a bit vague. But `content` accepts name, value pairs; and I think that it's supposed to post these back as form fields.

It appears that the xhrPost method does not automatically serialize objects to JSON strings. To be safe, I'll do that first. I'm using the `dojo.toJson` method that I found documented [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/toJson.html) and are assuming is avaliable.

```
var xfer_data = [ {"ID":"1",
"Device #":"176",
"Access #":"002-20",
"Address":"MH48 STEWART & CRANDON",
"TP":"MF",
"Curr":" ",
"Last":" ",
"Tdy":"8.6",
"-1":"8.6",
"-2":"8.6",
"-3":"8.6",
"-4":"8.6",
"-5":"8.6",
"-6":"8.6",
"Wk-1":"8.6",
"Wk-2":"8.6",
"Wk-3":"8.6",
"Wk-4":"8.6",
"Alarm":" R ",
"In":"14"} ];

var xfer_data_json = dojo.toJson( xfer_data );

var xhrArgs = {
   url: "/cgi-bin/DataExport.cgi?cmd=file",
   content: {data: xfer_data_json},
   load: function(data) {
     alert('Posted!' + data);
   },
   error: function(error) {
     alert('Error! ' + error);
   }
 };
 dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

The perl side then becomes regular CGI processing, with the need to deserialize JSON data (also untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;
use CGI;
use JSON;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

if ($cgi->param('cmd') eq 'file') {
   my $data_json = $cgi->param('data');
   my $devices = JSON::from_json( $data_json );

   foreach my $device (@$devices) {
        printf ("device: id=%s access=%s address=%s\n", $device->{ID}, $device->{Access}, $device->{Address});
   }
}
```

Comment: Also note: the xhrPost documentation states that it is depreciated in favor of xhr http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/request/xhr.html#dojo-request-xhr

Comment: Tried your example but still only see cmd=file in QUERY_STRING $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}.  Just noticed in the doc about being depreciated so I'll convert the code over to request.  Interesting though if I change it the request to dojo.xhrGet() I receive more data in my perl script on the server: QUERY_STRING = cmd=file&0=%5Bobject%20Object%5D

Comment: @GoinOff With regard to QUERY_STRING When you're using CGI with HTTP POST method form data may transferred both by the query string and on STDIN; I think you'll find xhrPost is sending some data via STDIN. But the HTTP PUT method needs everything needs to be squashed into QUERY_STRING which xhrGet() is doing.

Comment: @GoinOff Thanks for providing more info. I'd say given that you're seeing 'object%20object...' dojo does not handle JSON serialization for you. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks snoopy, getting closer modified my client side request. see original post.

Comment: @GoinOff do you also see my perl-side changes to deserialize JSON?

Comment: You rock snoopy!! Key elements to success var xfer_data_json = dojo.toJson( xfer_data ); and on the server side my $devices = JSON::from_json( $data_json );

Comment: One last thing: I have 150 records in xfer_data and only 50 make it to the server..Is there a size restriction??

Comment: Found the problem with only 50 records being selected, it's on the dojo side of things..Will fix in the morning..